# How can I submitt App to App Store built in XCode 5 and iOS 7 SDK but keeping UI of iOS 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

My App is developed in XCode4.6 and is already available on App Store. Now app is crashing in iOS7.1. I don't want to change UI as its just couple of lines of code modification.
I have built app in XCode5 and with iOS7 base SDK and set deployment target to 5.0, but i am afraid that it will have iOS7 UI.
What shall i do to keep UI of iOS6?

Comment: I think Apple wont publish this in AppStore so you better update your UI to iOS 7 UI or at least to custom modern UI... because Apple really doesn't love old stuff :P

Comment: Ofcourse, but just two lines of code change will make me update whole UI. That is something strange to me. App is completely crashing on iOS7.1 and i need to upload a fix as soon as possible. I have included iOS6.1 SDK in XCode5 and everything is working fine. Now i see same device twice twice in XCode5. One launches App with iOS6.1 UI and one with iOS7 UI. Also when i publish App for Adhoc keeping iOS6 device, the ipa installs with iOS6 UI on iOS7 device as well.

Comment: According to apple more than 82% iOS device now running on iOS7 or later. So I would recommend you to have iOS7 support before submmiting.

Comment: @HardikKothari you can keep your UI the same, but you have to use Xcode 5 to submit your app to the App Store which means you are going to have to compile it for iOS 7, run the simulator/iOS device with iOS 7 and check your UI is correct as Apple could reject your app for that.

Comment: @sbarow I have used UITabbar and Segments and many more controls which are not looking appropriate in iOS 7. And i have no time to re-design whole app.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible.

Apple now require apps to be built with the iOS7 SDK, and doing so will give you the iOS 7 look and feel on iOS 7 devices. There is no way around this.

You've had 8-9 months to prepare